# How many secondary oscillators are connected to my PIC24F

Tags: pic, crystal, explorer-1632, pic24fj1024gb610

I have a PIC24F Development Board an [Explorer 16/32](https://www.microchip.com/developmenttools/ProductDetails/DM240001-3) with a [PIC24FJ1024GB610](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC24FJ1024GB610) General Purpose Plug-in Module (Part # [MA240023](https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/PartNO/MA240023#additional-summary))

I would like to create a simple program where the clock signal would be sourced from the Secondary Oscillator (SOSC), I would like to use one of the external oscillators (32.768KHz) on the development board, as shown in the picture below.

[image]
This is from the PIC24FJ1024GB610's [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC24FJ1024GA610-GB610-Family-Data-Sheet-DS30010074G.pdf)

However this is what confuses, in the [Explorer 16/32 schematic](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Explorer_16_32_Schematics_R6_3.pdf), crystal Y2 of 32.768 KHz is connected to the SOSCI (P73) and SOSCO (P74) of the microcontroller, and in the [PIC24FJ1024GB610 PIM schematic](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002423a.pdf), crystal X1 of 32.768 KHz is connected to SOSCI/RC13 (P73) and SOSCO/RC14 (P74).

A printout of the two crystal schematics is shown below.

[image]

do the SOSCI and SOSCO pins have 2 32.768KHz oscillators connected to it, or do we disconnect one oscillator and keep the other? (I don't see any jumpers).

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link your provided [for the PIM module](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002423a.pdf). The "Pin Mapping" section explain this:

> There are several device pins that don’t have a one-to-one connection
>   to the ICE connector. Some are hard-wired to a certain location, while
>   others are mapped to the connector through jumpers.

In the Table 1, you can see thant the SOSCI and SOSCO pins are not connected to a PIM pin.

[image: Pin Mapping Exception]

The Crystal on the Explorer 16/32 will not be used. Only the one on the PIM.

Comment: So the Secondary OSC at the explorer DB is not connected to the PIM header, but the one on the PIM is connected. Thanks for clearing that up